# C Issue #3 - Double-Linked List for a List of Students

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am having some troubles with **adding a new element in a sorted way**, so while the element is being added it is **placed in the right place so it is always sorted, but the results keep mixing their info.** I am prepping for an exam so any help would be useful, Thank you all!

[Here is an image of the results how it looks when I run the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Arc.png)

*For clarification of the problem. The task is to define a structure that represents a linked list containing the following information of students: name, surname, index number, year of study, average grade. And the list should be sorted while adding each new student to it, but so that at the beginning of the list we can find students with the highest average, but with for those students who have the same average preference is given to those who are in the higher year of study. At the output print data for those students who have an average higher than given.*

*This is all of the code that I wrote for this program.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    typedef struct student
    {
        char *ime, *prezime, *br_indeksa;
        int godina_studija;
        float prosek;
        struct student *next;
        struct student *prev;
    }Student;
    
    void Print(Student *p);
    void PrintAboveAverage(Student *p, float average);
    void AddSorted(Student **p);
    Student* MakeNewStudent();
    Student* AlocateNew();
    void CopyString(char *st1);
    
    int main()
    {
        Student *studenti = NULL;
        
        int n, i;
        printf("BROJ STUDENTA: "); scanf("%d", &n);
        for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
            AddSorted(&studenti);
        
        Print(studenti);
        PrintAboveAverage(studenti,7.3);
        
        return 0;
    }
    
    void Print(Student *p)
    { 
        printf("\n\nSTUDENTI: \n");
        if (!p) printf("LISTA JE PRAZNA!\n");
        else
            while (p)
            {
                printf("IME: %s\tPREZIME: %s\tINDEKS: %s\tPROSEK: %.2f\tGODINA: %d\n",
                        p->ime, p->prezime, p->br_indeksa, p->prosek, p->godina_studija);
                p = p->next;
            }
    }
    
    void PrintAboveAverage(Student *p, float average)
    {
        printf("\n\nSTUDENTI SA PROSEKOM PREKO %.2f: \n", average);
        if (!p) printf("LISTA JE PRAZNA!\n");
        else
            while (p)
            {
                if ( p->prosek >= average )
                    printf("IME: %s\tPREZIME: %s\tINDEKS: %s\tPROSEK: %.2f\tGODINA: %d\n",
                            p->ime, p->prezime, p->br_indeksa, p->prosek, p->godina_studija);
                p = p->next;
            }
    }
    
    Student* AlocateNew()
    {
        Student *newStudent;
        newStudent = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));
        if (!newStudent)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Greska u alokaciji memorije. \n");
            exit(1);
        }
        return newStudent;
    }
    
    Student* MakeNewStudent()
    {
        Student *newStudent = AlocateNew();
        char tmp[100];
        
        printf("IME: "); scanf("%s", tmp);
        newStudent->ime = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmp)+1);
        if (!newStudent->ime)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Greska u alokaciji memorije. \n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(newStudent->ime,tmp);
        
        printf("PREZIME: "); scanf("%s", tmp);
        newStudent->prezime = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmp)+1);
        if (!newStudent->prezime)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Greska u alokaciji memorije. \n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(newStudent->prezime,tmp);
         
        printf("INDEKS: "); scanf("%s", tmp);
        newStudent->br_indeksa = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmp)+1);
        if (!newStudent->br_indeksa)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Greska u alokaciji memorije. \n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(newStudent->br_indeksa,tmp);
            
        printf("PROSEK: ");     scanf("%f", &newStudent->prosek);
        printf("GODINA: ");     scanf("%d", &newStudent->godina_studija);
        
        newStudent->next = NULL;
        newStudent->prev = NULL;
        
        putchar('\n');
        return newStudent;
    }
    
    void AddSorted(Student **p)
    {
        Student *newStudent = MakeNewStudent();
        Student *tmp = *p;
    
        /* sorted list, so that on the start of the list
           we can see the students with the biggest average grade 
           and students who have the same average, advantage have the ones in higher years */   
    
        if ( *p == NULL )
            *p = newStudent;
        else if ( ( newStudent->prosek > tmp->prosek ) || ( ( newStudent->prosek = tmp->prosek ) && 
                ( newStudent->godina_studija > tmp->godina_studija ) ) )
                {
                    newStudent->next = *p;
                    (*p)->prev = newStudent;
                    *p = newStudent;
                }
        else
        {
            while(tmp && (( newStudent->prosek > tmp->prosek ) || 
                         (( newStudent->prosek = tmp->prosek ) && 
                         ( newStudent->godina_studija > tmp->godina_studija ) )))
                            tmp = tmp->next;
            newStudent->next = tmp->next;
            if ( tmp->next != NULL )
                newStudent->next->prev = newStudent;
            
            tmp->next = newStudent;
            newStudent->prev = tmp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `==` to compare for equality. `=` is the assignment operator.

Comment: Yeah, that works! Now they are all unique, although I found out that I haven't really sorted them properly, although that's a different issue. Thank you, Ian!

Comment: In `AddSorted`, the `while` loop test condition is the same as the `else if` test condition (apart from the additional test for non-null `tmp`. You probably need to logically negate the condition with `!`, i.e. `while(tmp && !(...`. Also that `while(tmp` should probably be `while(tmp->next` so that `tmp` never becomes NULL.

Comment: Bam! It works!! Thank you so much Ian, I understand now. All the best to you! :)